# Creating a new list from 2 lists based on the index return from a third list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Say I have the following lists (Python 3):

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
letters = [a,b,a,b,c,c]
state = [False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

What I am looking to do is receive two inputs from the user for 2 index positions within the range of the length of list letters. If it is the case that his choices correspond to matching letters such as a and a (index 0 and 2), there must be a change in the list state from False to True for said positions. Afterwards, it should create a new list depending on the new state list, getting the index item from numbers if the element in state is False and getting the index item from the list letters if the state is true:

```
choice = 0
choice_2 = 2
if letters[choice] == letters[choice_2]:
   change state[choice] and state[choice_2] to True
create fourth list from list state and use values from numbers and letters
For i in range(len(state)):
    if state[i] == True:
       element in index[i] of list letters is used
    else:
       element in index[i] of list numbers is used
```

Creating a new list such that:

```
new_list = [a,2,a,4,5,6]
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
letters = ["a","b","a","b","c","c"]
state = [False, False, False, False, False, False]


choice1 = input("Enter Your 1st choice: ")
choice2 = input("Enter Your 2nd choice: ")

if letters[choice1] == letters[choice2]:
    state[choice1] = (not state[choice1])
    state[choice2] = (not state[choice2])

List = []

print state
for i in range(len(state)):
    if state[i] == True:
        List.append(letters[i])
    else:
        List.append(numbers[i])

print List
```

Input:

```
Enter Your 1st choice: 0
Enter Your 1st choice: 2
```

Output:

```
['a', 2, 'a', 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution: use list comprehension to create the fourth list, which I named `mixed`.

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
letters = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
states = [False, False, False, False, False, False]

choice1 = 0
choice2 = 2

if letters[choice1] == letters[choice2]:
    states[choice1] = True
    states[choice2] = True

mixed = [letter if use_letter else number
         for number, letter, use_letter in zip(numbers, letters, states)]

print numbers
print letters
print states
print mixed
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
[True, False, True, False, False, False]
['a', 2, 'a', 4, 5, 6]
```

Note that in the code, I zipped together three lists and use elements from the `states` list to pick elements from the other two. Also, I renamed `state` (singular) to `states` (plural) to be consistent with the other lists' naming convention.